# Can you control content displayed in Dita output based on user privileges

Tags: jsp, dita

I have the task to convert html help content that currently resides in .jsp files to DITA. In the java server pages there are statements such as:

```
<%if (!Privileges.isRootOr(curUser, Privileges.DEPLOY_AGENT)){ %>
You do not have permission to view this page.  Please contact your System Administrator.
<%} else{ %>
The Config Manager provides administrators ability to ...
```

Can this if else statement be duplicated in the html output used for WebHelp to obtain the same effect. Currently the .jsp pages provide the context sensitive help for parts of the Java web application. My goal is to use WebHelp generated from DITA for the context sensitive help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `audience` attribute in your DITA content to conditionally mark sections for content. If you're not rendering the DITA content to HTML dynamically, you can generate multiple versions of the HTML per audience and then show correct HTML output based on user rights.